# Python spynner login page issue

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to create basic script to pass `username/password` and hit enter to just login on web site but i am having problem in click steps its successfully filling out username and password but not clicking on submit button.

```
import spynner
b = spynner.Browser()
b.show()
b.load('https://example.com)
b.wk_fill('input[name="j_username"]', 'user1')
b.wk_fill('input[name="j_password"]', '12345')
b.click('#submitBtn')
b.browse()
```

Here is the page source view where click defined

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){
            $('.submitBtn').hover(
                // mouseover
                function(){ $(this).addClass('submitBtnHover'); },

                // mouseout
                function(){ $(this).removeClass('submitBtnHover'); }
            );
        });
        </script> 
    <tr> 
        <td class="loginSubmit" colspan="2"> 
            <button value="enter" class="submitBtn" type="submit"><span>enter</span></button> 
        </td> 
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer myself when i tried following... and it works!!!

```
b.click('button[value="enter"]', True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used `submitBtn` as a class in your HTML code, but are referring to `#submitBtn` which will look for an element with ID `submitBtn`

You can either change your Python code to look for the class, or you can change the HTML code and assign `submitBtn` ID to the button.